# Aggregate array type in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame orders:

```
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
|               Id|    Order  |        Gender|
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
|             1622|[101330001]|          Male|
|             1622|   [147678]|          Male|
|             3837|  [1710544]|          Male|
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+
```

which I want to groupBy on Id and Gender and then aggregate orders.
I am using org.apache.spark.sql.functions package and code looks like:

```
DataFrame group = orders.withColumn("orders", col("order"))
                .groupBy(col("Id"), col("Gender"))
                .agg(collect_list("products"));
```

However since column Order is of type array I get this exception because it expects a primitive type:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No handler for Hive udf class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFCollectList because: Only primitive type arguments are accepted but array<string> was passed as parameter 1
```

I have looked in the package and there are sort functions for arrays but no aggregate functions. Any idea how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can define your own function and register it as UDF

```
val userDefinedFunction = ???
val udfFunctionName = udf[U,T](userDefinedFunction)
```

Then instead of then pass that column inside that function so that it gets converted into primitive type and then pass it in the with Columns method.

Something like this:

```
val dataF:(Array[Int])=>Int=_.head

val dataUDF=udf[Int,Array[Int]](dataF)


DataFrame group = orders.withColumn("orders", dataUDF(col("order")))
                .groupBy(col("Id"), col("Gender"))
                .agg(collect_list("products"));
```

I hope it works !