# How can I integrate/compute dot product in Pyspark 1.6.1?

Tags: pyspark, integral, dot-product

I have the following table in pyspark 1.6.1:

```
+--------+-----+--------------------+
|     key|carid|                data|
+--------+-----+--------------------+
|    time|    1|[0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0...|
|velocity|    1|[2.0, 2.1, 2.3, 0...|
|    time|    2|[0.1, 0.35, 0.4, 0..|
|velocity|    2|[1.0, 1.1, 3.3, 0...|
|    time|    3|[0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0...|
|velocity|    3|[2.3, 2.1, 2.3, 0...|
+--------+-----+--------------------+
```

That is I have a number of cars and for each car I have an array with non-equidistant timestamps and an array with velocity values. I want to compute the distance each car has driven:

```
+-----+------ -+
|carid|distance|
+-----+--------+
|    1|     100|
|    2|     102|
|    3|      85|
+-----+--------+
```

I want to compute this by Trapezoidal Numerical Integration (or simply scalar_product(diff(timestamp), velocity). How can I do this in pyspark 1.6.1?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this code on real data and let us know if it solved your problem?

```
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

df = sc.parallelize([
    ['time',    1, [0.2, 0.4, 0.5 ]],
    ['velocity',1, [2.0, 2.1, 2.3 ]],
    ['time',    2, [0.1, 0.35, 0.4]],
    ['velocity',2, [1.0, 1.1, 3.3 ]]
]).toDF(('key', 'carid', 'data'))
df.show()

df1 = df.sort('carid','key').groupby("carid").agg(f.collect_list("data").alias("timeVelocityPair"))

def modify_values(l):
    val = np.trapz(l[1], x=l[0])
    return float(val)
modified_val = f.udf(modify_values, FloatType())
final_df = df1.withColumn("distance", modified_val("timeVelocityPair")).drop("timeVelocityPair")
final_df.show()
```

Comment: When I execute "df1 = ..." I always get the error message "No handler for Hive udf class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFCollectList because: Only primitive type arguments are accepted but array<double> was passed as parameter 1..;"..

Comment: For me it works but to solve this error I would suggest to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117360/aggregate-array-type-in-spark-dataframe) or may be go for an upgrade to next version (check out this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10427)). For now can you run this code on standalone system instead of cluster and see if the solution is working for you?

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a solution in pyspark 1.6.1, not scala, and upgrading is no option for me.

Comment: @Mandy - btw above solution is not in Scala but Pyspark.